# Getting the steps down for Quick FInd algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, find, set

my goal is to manually write out the steps of the quick find algorithm to full understand the concept. My problem is that I don't understand the sequence it takes to decide whether to check if two objects are connected or not. What I'm referring to is Princeton's explanation of this algorithm that I found: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

Why is there a decision to check whether or not id[3] and id[6] are equal?

This may be the wrong approach but I want to use the algorithm to got though say 6  union steps to form a set.

For this I will use the following set and union steps...

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

9-0 4-6 2-1 7-6 2-3 4-9
```

Step 1: `9-0`

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
```

Step 2: `4-6`

```
[0,1,2,3,6,5,6,7,8,0]
```

Step 3: `2-1`

```
[0,1,1,3,6,5,6,7,8,0]
```

Step 4: `7-6`

```
[0,1,1,3,6,5,6,6,8,0]
```

Step 5: `2-3`

```
[0,3,3,3,6,5,6,6,8,0]
```

Step 6: `4-9`

```
[0,3,3,3,0,5,0,0,8,0]
```

Can someone confirm or deny the right use of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation of the sequence is correct.

`Quick Find` logic is as follows :

`Find`
Check if p and q have the same id.
`Union`
To merge components containing p and q, change all entries with id[p] to id[q]

To answer your question

> Why is there a decision to check whether or not id[3] and id[6] are
>   equal?

This is because of the way the internal array is defined. If both 3 and 6 have the same entries then they are **defined** as connected.